# MacOS VS Code C++ error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors

On visual studio code, on a 2020 I7 Mac, on any c++ program (it's the only ones I checked to be fair), I get this error:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/creaturesceptique/projects/helloworld/" && g++ Wontwork.cpp -o 

Wontwork && "/Users/creaturesceptique/projects/helloworld/"Wontwork
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.1 seconds
```

My c++ code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm very new to this so please be tolerant to my stupidity...

Btw I am using the basic Code Runner and the microsoft c/c++ extensions.

Comment: The code looks fine, it's likely the [lack of] configuration of VS Code. How did you install your compiler?

Comment: C++ is not a script langauge.

Comment: Seems like VS Code default settings is *not* to save the file to disk before compiling.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, so long as you have all the correct extensions running in VS code, and have installed command line developer tools in the terminal, you should be fine. Sometimes VS Code is dumb so just exit the program or restart your mac.

Answer (score -1):

I was removing x-code and installing it again, updating brew as well.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
brew doctor
xcode-select -p
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).